# ELAN touchpad can't scroll Windows 10 start menu

Tags: drivers, touchpad, elan

I can't seem to scroll on the Windows 10 start menu with an ELAN touchpad. It scrolls on other places though like the Settings app or any other Win32 application but not on the start menu. I've already tried the registry edit for **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Elantech\SmartPad\ScrollControl_Mode** set to 1 but when I restart, it keeps reverting back to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an even better solution than working with the basic ELAN driver, I followed [this guide on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/jmptjn/turn_old_elan_touchpad_into_precision_touchpad/) which transformed the ELAN touchpad to a precision one which introduces more features and smoother handling!

In case the Reddit post gets taken down, I'll repost the steps here:

> 1. Download [this](https://support.lenovo.com/rs/en/downloads/ds120858) or [that](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/r0hgf10w.exe) complimentary of [u/BredzPro](https://www.reddit.com/u/BredzPro/)
> 2. Begin the install and when prompted select extract only
> 3. Open device manager and find your ELAN touchpad
> 4. Right-click + click properties
> 5. In the drivers tab click update drivers
> 6. Click "browse my computer for software"
> 7. Click "have disk"
> 8. Select the file "ELAN.inf" in the farthest subfolder where you extracted the .exe
> 9. Select "ok" and ignore the warning
> 10. Reboot your computer
> 11. The touchpad should stop working
> 12. Go into device manager
> 13. There should be an unknown device that wasn't there before
> 14. Right-click + click properties
> 15. On the drivers tab, click update drivers
> 16. Like last time click manual
> 17. It should still have the folder used for the last driver in the text box
> 18. Click next
> 19. You should be good, enjoy!

NOTE: For step 8, I couldn't find any `ELAN.inf` file so I went with the `ETD.inf` file. The rest of the steps should go as planned though.